# Multiple RegisterAll registrations using the same set of singletons with SimpleInjector

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, ioc-container, simple-injector

I'm building a plugin system for an e-commerce project with Simple Injector. I'm using `RegisterAll` to register all implementation of a `IPaymentProvider` and of a `IResourceRegistrar` (and in the fure more).

But this creates a new instance each time. [Here](http://simpleinjector.codeplex.com/discussions/360001) is it suggested to use `RegisterSingle` on each type. But how to achieve this in this case?

```cs
private static void RegisterMultipleUnderOneInterface(
    Container container, string name)
{
    IEnumerable<Type> pluginRegistrations =
        from dll in finder.Assemblies
        from type in dll.GetExportedTypes()
        where type.GetInterfaces().Any(i => i.Name == name)
        where !type.IsAbstract
        where !type.IsGenericTypeDefinition
        select type;

    if (pluginRegistrations.Any())
    {
        var @interface =
            pluginRegistrations.ElementAt(0).GetInterfaces()
            .First(i => i.Name == name);

        foreach (Type type in pluginRegistrations)
        {
            // HERE: register the type single somehow. 
        }

        container.RegisterAll(@interface, pluginRegistrations);
    }
}
```

`container.RegisterSingle(type)` does not work, as the types inherent from the same interface (`IPaymentProvider` or `IResourceRegistrar`). The `IPaymentProvider` implementing classes have constructors without parameters, the `IResourceRegistrar` with parameters.

I don't want to do something like this, it rather defeats the purpose of a IoC container

```cs
var constructor = type.GetConstructors()[0];

switch (name)
{
    case "IResourceRegistrar":
        container.RegisterSingle(type, () =>
        {
            return constructor.Invoke(new object[
            {
                container.GetInstance<ILanguageService>()});
            });
        break;
    case "IPaymentProvider":
    default:
        container.RegisterSingle(type, () =>
        {
            return constructor.Invoke(new object[] { });
        });
        break;
}
```

How to register these as singleton without the ugly switch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps I misunderstand, but RegisterSingle should work. You should be able to do this:

```cs
var types = ...

container.RegisterAll<IInterface>(types);

foreach (var type in types)
{
    container.RegisterSingle(type, type);
}
```

UPDATE:

So what you are trying to do is to automate the following configuration:

```cs
// A, B, C and D implement both I1 and I2.
container.RegisterSingle<A>();
container.RegisterSingle<B>();
container.RegisterSingle<C>();
container.RegisterSingle<D>();

container.RegisterAll<I1>(typeof(A), typeof(B), typeof(C), typeof(D));
container.RegisterAll<I2>(typeof(A), typeof(B), typeof(C), typeof(D));
```

This would typically be the way to automate this. So do four steps:

1. Find all types to register.
2. Register the found types as singleton.
3. Register the list of types as collection for `I1`.
4. Register the list of types as collection for `I2`.

This would look like this:

```
// using SimpleInjector.Extensions;

Type[] singletons = FindAllTypesToRegister();

foreach (Type type in singletons)
{
    container.RegisterSingle(type, type);
}

container.RegisterAll(typeof(I1), singletons);
container.RegisterAll(typeof(I2), singletons);
```

However, since you are trying to split this into two steps and create one generic method that can handle each step, you will have to ignore when a concrete singleton type has already been registered. You can either do this by:

- Ignoring the registration by catching the exception thrown from `RegisterSingle`.
- Override an existing registration by setting `container.Options.AllowOverridingRegistrations = true` before calling `RegisterSingle` (disabling it afterwards would be safest).

Comment: Then I get a 'Type has already been registered' exception for the second type in the list. It seems the key in Container.registrations is System.Type.

Comment: Ah,  I get it. A single type implements multiple interfaces. Are you sure those types aren't violating the Single Responsibility Principle? Perhaps you should split those types. Any way, just make sure a type get registered once.

Comment: What you can do by the way is (temporary) enabling overriding registrations by setting `container.Options.AllowOverridingRegistrations`. This prevents any exceptions from being thrown during `RegisterSingle` and is safe in your case since you would be replacing the type with the same type any way.

Comment: @jeroenk: I'm sorry, you are right about calling `container.RegisterSingle(type)`. The C# compiler will use `container.RegisterSingle<Type>(type)` for you, which is indeed not what you want. The [SimpleInjector.Extensions](http://nuget.org/packages/SimpleInjector.Extensions) package contains a `RegisterSingle(Type, Type)` extension method that allows you to do a non-generic registration. You have to call `container.RegisterSingle(type, type)` to make the registration. This actually is a design and it is something I will try to address in a future version of the framework.